# Whats the correct signature of receiveData:fromPeer:inSession:context: in swift?

Tags: swift, gamekit, ios8, gksession

im trying to rewrite my GameKit multiplayer game (local) in swift and have problems with some missing documentation for the language. I want to receive data from another peer so i set the dataReceiveHandler for my GKSession like this:

```
session.setDataReceiveHandler(self, withContext: nil)
```

in apples documentation it says that the dataReceiveHandler hast to implement a method with this signature:

```
SEL = -receiveData:fromPeer:inSession:context:
```

In the objective-c documentation is an example of how the signature should look like:

```
- (void) receiveData:(NSData *)data fromPeer:(NSString *)peer inSession: (GKSession *)session context:(void *)context;
```

if i try to rewrite this method in swift it looks like this:

```
func receiveData(data: NSData, fromPeer peer: String, inSession session: GKSession, withContext context: CMutableVoidPointer) {
    println("received data: \(data)")
}
```

and gives me this error when i receive a message:

> Domain=com.apple.gamekit.GKSessionErrorDomain Code=30500 "Invalid parameter for -setDataReceiveHandler:withContext:" UserInfo=0x178462840 {NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid parameter for -setDataReceiveHandler:withContext:, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The handler does not respond to the correct selector.}

this means my method has not the correct signature.
But what is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that i have to edit this again but i have the actual answer now:

DONT USE GKSESSION! IT IS DEPRECATED SINCE iOS7!

Use:

> MultipeerConnectivity.framework

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with renaming your parameters. You wrote `withContext context` instead of `context withContext`. The first name is the one that will be exposed to callers.

This should work:

```
func receiveData(data: NSData, fromPeer peer: String, inSession session: GKSession, context: CMutableVoidPointer) {
    println("received data: \(data)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to declare the types of the parameters as optionals (not sure whether this applies to the void pointer), i.e. `func receiveData(data: NSData?, fromPeer peer: String?, inSession session: GKSession?, withContext context: CMutableVoidPointer)` (you could also use `!` instead of `?` for implicitly unwrapped optionals).

Those parameters are pointers in Objective-C, i.e. they could be `nil`, which your current code cannot represent, thus it is does not have the correct signature. The way to represent possible `nil` values in Swift is to use optionals.

Comment: His error is coming from inside GameKit, which is an Objective-C library that doesn't know about Swift's optionals.